# How to use Sonar Qube with Eclipse RCP product to identify project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I'm trying to see if the Eclipse SonarQube plugin can help me to get a good understanding of an Eclipse RCP Product. My goal is to understand and identify all the dependencies between RCP projects that make up all of the Features included in the Product.

Is this even possible? If so, does anybody have an idea of how to approach this?

The immediate goal in identifying the dependencies between the RCP projects is to identify which projects are tightly coupled and then begin to asses how to go about refactoring projects to de-couple those that can be de-coupled.

I've used sonar in a similar fashion with JavaEE projects but not with Eclipse RCP projects.

Looking for some tips and guidance.

thanks,
mbeddedsoft.